# View files from s3 even after they have private access

Tags: javascript, reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

What I want is to securely add the s3 url in my img src but with some security. I CANNOT change the file permissions to public.Is there a way with tokens or some type of other workarounds.

Comment: I want to use it from the front-end,I think there will be a option to that.

Comment: Shikhar, the problem with "using it from the front-end" is that the front-end would need to have credentials, but they could be extracted by nefarious characters and all your files would then be accessible. That's why the security will need to be enforced by your back-end. An alternative is to use Cognito identity pools, but this would not be as fine-grained (eg it would allow access to a whole bucket or folder). Presumably, you would want your app to determine _exactly which_ files they are allowed to access.

Comment: Hi john, Will it be the same case if I am not setting my credentials in frontend as hardcoded but using sts credentials and token from an api call.

Comment: But how will you authenticate the request for STS credentials? You would need to be okay with _anybody_ being able to get those credentials, since you are not authenticating them.

Comment: The call for STS credentials will be fired only when inside the login and after getting a session token.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use S3 pre-signed URL. But you have to build a backend (either using ec2 or lambda, or anything that you want which have the role to access that bucket).

then in the back-end, you can use this script (for nodejs) idk what language you want to use.

```
const url = s3.getSignedUrl('getObject', {
    Bucket: "bucket-name",
    Key: "image/secret.jpg",
    Expires: 300 //300 seconds
})
```

return the url to your front-end

then you can use the url in your img src

Answer (score 0):

You can use signed URLs with expiration. Your application would need AWS credentials (or role to access S3 if running on ec2)

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/private-content-signed-urls.html

(ok, this documentation is for cloudfront, but you can use it directly with s3 too)